# Prove that the limiting distribution of $nF[X_{(2)}]$ Gamma(2,1).

Tags: probability, statistics

I am working on a problem stated in the title.

So far I know that the cdf for $X_{(2)}$ is 
$$F_{X_{(2)}}(x)=1-[1-F(x)]^n-nF(x)[1-F(x)]^{n-1}$$ and that I am to prove that 
$$nF(X_{(2)}) \rightarrow 1-e^{-x}-xe^{-x}$$

I do not know what to do when I take the limit as $n \rightarrow \infty$ ...

I appreciate your help.

Comment: You do not need to take $nF_{X_{(2)}}(x)$ here. You should find a limit of $\mathbb P(nF(X_{(2)})\leq x)$ where $F(x)=\mathbb P(X_1 \leq x)$.

Comment: Thank you, I will try doing that.

Comment: I was able to prove it, thank you!